# javascript sequence of promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I wrote the following code:

```
'use strict';

...

class Foo {
    constructor( ws, ontrack ) {
        this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
...
    }

    handleOffer( offer ) {
          var desc = offer;
          this.pc.setRemoteDescription( desc )
          .then( () => 
             navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints) 
            .then( (stream) => {
                console.log("getUserMedia done");
                stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => this.pc.addTrack(track, stream));
                this.pc.createAnswer( desc ) 
                .then( (answer) => {
                   console.log("createAnswer done");
                   desc = answer;   
                   this.pc.setLocalDescription( desc )
                   .then( () => this.ws.send( { type:"webrtc.answer", answer: desc } )); 
                } )
            } )
           );
    }

...
}
```

It does what is expected. However the nesting of several "then" produces a code that is, in my opinion, difficult to read.

Knows someone any alternative ?

I've tried with the (deprecated?) async/await. However, eclipse editor complains about "missing semicolon" immediately after any await or async in the code (why?)

(note: the are several related questions in stack exchange, but all the ones I've found talks about arrays).

Comment: async/await is nowhere near deprecation..

Comment: @LucaKiebel: Thanks or your interested in the issue. Unfortunatelly, for some reason, eclipse editor marks asyn/await as syntax errors.

Comment: Editors complain all the time. Most probably because yours still doesn't support ES6?

Comment: Maybe you aren't using a JS version recent enough to feature async/await

Comment: @NelsonOwalo: Eclipse is "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0). Build id: 20180917-1800".

Comment: @pasabaporaqui your ide version probably knows how to handle async/await (although I didn't check it) but you still need to set the right js version in the project settings

Comment: Sorry, I am not familier with Eclipse, tho i use Visual basic Code, and it doesnt support ES6/ async-await out of the box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain promises like this :

```
handleOffer( offer ) {
      var desc = offer;
      this.pc.setRemoteDescription( desc )
          .then( () => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints))
          .then( (stream) => {
              console.log("getUserMedia done");
              stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => this.pc.addTrack(track, stream));
              return this.pc.createAnswer( desc );
          }
          .then( (answer) => {
              console.log("createAnswer done");
              desc = answer;   
              return this.pc.setLocalDescription( desc );
          }
          .then( () => this.ws.send( { type:"webrtc.answer", answer: desc } )); 
}
```

And if you want to use async/await :

```
async handleOffer( offer ) {
      var desc = offer;
      await this.pc.setRemoteDescription( desc );

      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
      console.log("getUserMedia done");
      stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => this.pc.addTrack(track, stream));

      const answer = await this.pc.createAnswer( desc );
      console.log("createAnswer done");
      desc = answer;   

      await this.pc.setLocalDescription( desc );
      this.ws.send( { type:"webrtc.answer", answer: desc } )); 
}
```

Comment: "return this.pc.createAnswer( desc );" is return of a promise value of type "answer", not sure if it is the same that the nested "then".

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, buf if `this.pc.createAnswer` returns a promise that will resolve with an `answer`, then I think this bit of code should work

Answer (score 0):

USing ***async/await*** can reduce the promise nesting and improve readability:

EDIT: Moving all of the **then()** blocks will actually require more code with more async functions, I think this is pretty readable right now.

```
async function handleOffer(offer) {

    var desc = offer;
    try {
      const result = await func1(desc);
    } catch(e){
      //handle error
    }
  return result;
}

function func1(desc){
  return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream)=>{
       console.log("getUserMedia done");
       stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => this.pc.addTrack(track, stream));
       return this.pc.createAnswer( desc );
  })
}

handleOffer(offer)
.then((answer)=>{
   console.log("createAnswer done");
   let desc = answer;   
   this.pc.setLocalDescription( desc )
   .then(()=> this.ws.send( { type:"webrtc.answer", answer: desc } )); 
})
```

Comment: I'd upvote for the advice of using `async/await` but please move all your `.then` calls into the handleOffer function and turn them into await statements :)

Comment: Unfortunately eclipse seems to accept only ES6 (today, 2018-Nov-14) and async/await is  ES8 ?

Comment: @squeekyDave can you check my edited answer and tell me what's wrong with that ? It doesn't seem to require more async functions but I'm not really into async/await so I'm not sure I'm doing it right

Comment: @Logar You either need to save the result from **await** in a variable and return it or return directly **await someFunc*()**, because this will be your promise.
When you call the async function, you will be able to call **.then()** and in that block there will be the result of your await function that you have **returned** from the async function.

Comment: could you clarify "async await handleOffer(offer) {}" ?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Apologies, await was a typo, thank you for pointing it out.
It is only async function someName(){};

Comment: @pasabaporaqui Yes, **async/await** is ES7/ES8.

Comment: @Logar My solution is not the best, its based on my own interpretation of the problem. Absolutely, there is no problem to chain promises, just **async/await** can make the code a bit more readable and help you with many nested **then()** blocks.